# SwiftUI best way to make navigation from profile tabbar item

Tags: swift, swiftui

First project written on **SwiftUI**. Got trouble to make navigation.

If I want to navigate like: **Profile -> Edit Profile -> another view**

**Not sure if this good idea to use this:**

```
@State private var navigateToEditProfile = false
if navigateToEditProfile{
    EditProfileView()
}
```

**Also tried to use this with next structure: body -> ScrollView -> VStack -> NavigationView**

But this is show me nothing at all... show only if I remove parent stack NavigationView, but then tap is not working!

```
NavigationView{
    NavigationLink(destination: EditProfile(){
       Button(){
           Row(rowActive: false, icon: "icn-edit", title: "Edit Profile")
       }
    }
}
```

Works only present, but I can't do it .overFullScren

```
Button(action: { self.navigateToEdit.toggle() }){
                        Row(rowActive: false, icon: "icn-edit", title: "Edit Profile")
                    }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                        .sheet(isPresented: $navigateToEdit){
                        EditProfile().environmentObject(ProfileViewModel.shared)
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Who people who looking solution to make present in full screen... I made my own solution. You're welcome! ;)

```
extension UIViewController {
func present<Content: View>(style: UIModalPresentationStyle = .automatic, @ViewBuilder builder: () -> Content) {
    let toPresent = UIHostingController(rootView: AnyView(EmptyView()))
    toPresent.modalPresentationStyle = style
    toPresent.rootView = AnyView(
        builder()
            .environment(\.viewController, toPresent)
    )
    self.present(toPresent, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}